# Like Button on my website product pages

Tags: e-commerce, facebook-social-plugins

I own a website selling playing cards. I have created a facebook page for my website.  I would like the small like buttons on each product page, but when I tried to get code, it did not work as I need to be a certified facebook developer.

How do I register as a developer on Facebook?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What code are you trying to use? Can you show us? You can get the code for the like buttons here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You can put the URL as your Facebook page and the "like count" will sync up instead of having two separate counts.

If you just want a straight forward like button you don't need to be certified or registered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers.  The code I am trying to use is from one of my product pages from my own website. Here is the code. http://www.playingcardsonly.co.uk/buy/find-playing-cards-by-brand/bee-playing-cards-red-backed-multipack-deal.htm  Then when I click on get code a window pops up saying " Only verified developers can be added as listed developers of this application. Read http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17580 for details."